# when a form reappears, auto run a function C#

Tags: c#

I have two win forms, f1 and f2. When I click on row headers of a datagridview on f1, f1 hide, f2 show, and data pass from f1 to f2. Now after users work on f2 and click on "close", f2 hide and f1 show. I've created function in f1 to catch whatever changes users made on the database. Problem is how I can call this function automatically instead of using a button when f2 hide and f1 show? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before hiding the Form1 (f1) and after the Form2 (f2) creation pass to the f2 an Action delegate that will be called by f2 when it closes. This delegate method will be inside the class Form1 and will reactivate the hidden instance

```
public class Form2: Form
{
    public Action ReactivateParent;

    .... form2 methods ....

    // Here I call the ReactivateParent inside the FormClosed event handler
    // of Form2, but these lines can also in a button click event 
    // that terminates the Form2 instance....
    protected void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ReactivateParent != null) 
           ReactivateParent();
    }
}
```

Now in Form1, when you prepare to show Form2 instance bind the Action delegate

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ReactivateParent += ReactivateMe;
this.Hide
f2.Show();
...
```

and add a method to Form1 named ReactivateMe

```
private void ReactivateMe()
{
    // Add here whatever you need to update your Form1 instance....
    ....
    // Reshow the now updated Form1 instance...
    this.Show();

}
```

The advantage of this approach lies in the fact that Form2 is not concerned about what is done in the ReactivateParent and every other form in your application can reuse the functionality of Form2 and being informed when the Form2 instance closes.

To improve further this pattern you could also consider to modify the Action delegate to receive an instance of a custom class that will be filled by the Form2 instance with the data modified. This could help avoiding a call to the database to update the Form1 instance.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is how I can call this function automatically instead of using
>   a button

Well then call that function in Form constructor or handle FormLoad event and call that function in event handler.

Comment: i see no reason for the -1 this is the correct answer

Comment: Thanks. Load event fired when f1 first appeared, after it hid and reappeared the load event fired again? I don't think so. Perhaps there's some other event.

Answer (score -1):

There is an event in a form's Events named `Shown`. This will run every time the form reappears.

I hope this helps.

**Edit:**

Try this instead:

```
this.Hide();
f2.ShowDialog();

MethodUpdateValues();
this.Show();
```

This will pause at the second line and continue when you close f2.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested on the Shown event. when f1 first appeared, Shown event fired, and when f1 reappeared and f2 hid, Shown didn't fire again. What I wish is exactly at this moment the function be triggered.

Comment: thanks, I just saw your update. I tested on Steve's solution, it worked fine.

Comment: @Viviannne Glad to help. If my answer was good enough, then would you consider accepting it? There is no accepted answer as of yet, but another person satisfied you earlier.